# How to insert Listview.Builder in Listview.Builder item

Tags: flutter, dart

### Parent Code

---

how to insert my listviewBuilder in listViewBuilder item
this is my parent code

```
 Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              decoration: Ui.getBoxDecoration(),
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var _comment =
                      controller.commentWithDetailDtoList.elementAt(index);
                  return TimelineCommentItemWidget(comment: _comment);
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                itemCount: controller.commentWithDetailDtoList.length,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

### Child Code

---

and this is my child code

```
 Visibility(
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var reply = comment.replies.elementAt(index);
          return TimelineCommentRepliesItemWidget(comment: reply);
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        itemCount: comment.replies.length,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code.

Please check this out.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(itemBuilder : (BuildContext context , int i) {
         return   _innerWidget();
                
    } , itemCount : 2 , shrinkWrap: true,separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10.0), );
  }
}

Widget  _innerWidget(){
  return  ListView.builder(itemBuilder : (BuildContext context , int i) {
  
        return Text('hello');
 
    }, itemCount: 2,shrinkWrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this code is work for me, i think i missed this  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),